# List of numbers which the program determines to be prime or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The program goes like this: the user inputs x number of values which will be stored into a list. The program then goes through each number in the list, and determines whether it is prime or not.

I've been trying to figure out how I'd do this, however, now I'm really confused and the program doesn't work. How can I fix the program to make it actually work?

Here is what I've got so far:

```
print("Hello User, this is the Prime Numbers Game!")
print("You will be required to input 5 numbers, and the game will return which numbers are prime, and which numbers aren't")

new_list = []
counter = 0
counter1 = 0

while counter < 5:
    new_list.append(int(input()))
    counter += 1


index = 0

for index in range(0, int(enumerate(new_list, start = 1)):
    for i in range(2, new_list[index]):
        if new_list[index] % i != 0:
            print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS PRIME")
        elif new_list[index] < 2:
            print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS PRIME")
        elif new_list[index] % i == 0:
            print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS NOT PRIME")
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean _exactly_?

Answer (score 0):

So there are couple things that may help you out.

Firstly, you are missing a closing parenthesis on the for loop line.

Secondly, using enumerate in this case is not necessary as you do not need to worry about working with the value and index. Just using a for loop will suffice! Take a look at this link for more information about enumerate (http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Thirdly, the logic in the inner for loop is a little bit off. Just because a number does not divide by the current number being checked, it does not mean that it is prime. It must not divide by **ALL** numbers between 2 and n-1 (or in other words, only divide by 1 and itself).

I have made some changes in the code to reflect my statement above.

```
print("Hello User, this is the Prime Numbers Game!")
print("You will be required to input 5 numbers, and the game will return which numbers are prime, and which numbers aren't")

new_list = []
counter = 0
counter1 = 0

while counter < 5:
    new_list.append(int(input()))
    counter += 1


index = 0

for index in range(0, len(new_list)):
    isPrime = True
    for i in range(2, new_list[index]):
        if new_list[index] % i == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
        elif new_list[index] < 2:
            break


    if (isPrime):
        print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS PRIME")
    else:
        print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS NOT PRIME")
```

Comment: Thank you! However, can you break down how the two for loops work please, so it's a bit easier to understand them. It would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The outer loop iterates (goes through) the list of numbers the user entered. For each iteration of the outer loop, index is the variable to represent the iteration. The inner loop starts at the number 2 and goes up to new_list[index] which for iteration 1, would be the first number the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution. It will also work with numbers 1 & 2 which are special cases in the logic you use:

```
print("Hello User, this is the Prime Numbers Game!")
print("You will be required to input 5 numbers, and the game will return which numbers are prime, and which numbers aren't")

new_list = []
counter = 0
counter1 = 0

while counter < 5:
    new_list.append(int(input()))
    counter += 1

print(new_list)


for index in range(0, len(new_list)):
    if new_list[index] <= 2:
        if new_list[index] == 1:
            print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS NOT A PRIME")
        else:
            print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS A PRIME")
        continue
    for counter in range(2, new_list[index]):
        if new_list[index] % counter == 0:
            print(str(new_list[index]) + " IS NOT A PRIME")
            break
        if counter==new_list[index] -1: #this means you have gone through all numbers and found nothing dividable
            print(str(new_list[index])+ " IS A PRIME")
```